# Using matrices in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, python-requests

How can I take the output (`x_matrix` and `y_matrix`) from `get_x_and_y_matrix` and use these matrices as input for the `ols_coefficients` function? I am getting an error message every time I do it.

```
def get_x_and_y_matrix(data_set):
    ones = np.ones(shape=(len(data_set), 1))
    x = data_set[:, 0:2]
    y_matrix = data_set[:, 2]
    x_matrix = np.concatenate((ones, x), axis=1)
    return x_matrix, y_matrix

def ols_coefficients(x, y):
    x, y = get_x_and_y_matrix(data_set=generate_data(n_obs))
    intercept = np.ones(shape=(len(x), 1))
    new_x = np.concatenate((intercept, x), axis=1)
    beta_hat = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(intercept, new_x)), np.dot(intercept, y))
    return beta_hat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the return from `get_x_and_y_matrix` function in variables `x` and `y` and then pass them as arguments to `ols_coefficients`.

```
def get_x_and_y_matrix(data_set):
    # rest of the function
    return x_matrix, y_matrix

def ols_coefficients(x, y):
    # rest of the function
    return beta_hat

x, y = get_x_and_y_matrix(data_set)
beta = ols_coefficients(x, y)
```